# where is my beautifulsoup.py file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I bought a book on data visualizations and after downloading Python was directed to download beautiful soup and "save the beautiful soup python.py file in the directory that I plan to save my code in."

There is no beautiful soup .py file in the beautiful soup download just a bunch of other files. It's like a cruel nerd joke.

Of the numerous files within the Beautiful Soup download which one should I save as "beautifulsoup.py"?

Comment: So, you'd like us to comment on installation instructions which we can't see, from a third party, which don't work with a download which you don't identify? Would you like us to tell you which card you picked?

Comment: @Marcin I was appealing to someone with experience installing beautiful soup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would ignore those instructions - putting commonly used 3rd party libraries in with your own code isn't really the way to do it.

You'll want to be using `beautifulsoup4` now, so you should either `pip` or `easy_install` that... then you'll be able to use it as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.